# How to read (decipher) this strings?

Tags: reactjs

All code implements adding or removing classes(toggle).
I commented strings.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isActive: false,
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ isActive: !state.isActive }));   // stirng №1
  };  

  render() {
    const { isActive } = this.state;    // stirng №2

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Try it</button>   //stirng №3
        <div className={isActive ? 'mystyle' : ''}>   //stirng №4
          This is a DIV element.
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How to read (decipher) this strings? Not only explanations of what they do, but how they are read

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ isActive: !state.isActive }));   // stirng №1
  };
```

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React
>   that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the
>   updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user
>   interface in response to event handlers and server responses.

This is using the "updater function form", it executes a callback function with how the state should be modified. In this case, it's setting "isActive" to the inverse of the current state value of "isActive".

It's also using a short form of Arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions Read up on that there

```
const { isActive } = this.state;    // stirng №2
```

This is using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to "unpack" the "isActive" value from the state (the state is an object). So instead of accesing the value using "this.state.isActive", now you can just use "isActive".

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Try it</button>   //stirng №3
```

"onClick" is a Javascript event handler, basically it says that "when this button is clicked, execute this function". The function being "handleClick" defined above that toggles the "isActive" state.

Hope that helps!